# Open 'billing' as initial step in onepage checkout in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have done some changes to the onepage checkout process on Magento (1.7) and have made Billing the first step - how can I enable this to automatically open up - as currently I have to click the 'billing' tab to open this up - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to make it go to the billing address info or payment info tab?

Check the opcheckout.js file under skin/frontend/base/default/js

Examine some of the functions in there, particularly the gotoSection() function. Calling it like this:

`this.gotoSection('payment', true);`

on your page would make it jump to the payment info section, for example.

Edit: There is also the onepage controller that you can override and change the steps- look under Mage_Checkout_OnepageController for the $result variable and how it is changed. Example:

```
$result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
```